# Redirect after saving form; and yet use wp_die()

Tags: ajax

I'm trying to redirect the user to a specific location. The redirect is a part of the function that processes ajax call. So the ending lines of my code are as follows -

wp_redirect("/dashboard/");
wp_die(1);

Now, I'm not able to figure out what exactly is wrong with this approach. I want to tell AJAX that the execution was successful and also redirect the user to proper location.

How do I achieve this? Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Use `exit` instead of `wp_die` because the redirect does not exit by default, and `wp_die` kills everything.

Comment: `exit()` and `die()` are equivalent in PHP. `wp_die()` uses `die()` by default. Can you explain what you are saying @SamuelElh? What `wp_die()` kills using `die()` that `exit()` doesn't?

Comment: I was after this, try `wp_redirect('/dashboard/');exit;` works while `wp_redirect('/dashboard/');wp_die(1);` won't.

Comment: I'm guessing a better approach is to use window.location.href( response.data.location ); in jQuery. This would actually tell the browser to redirect to perform redirect after AJAX is complete.

Comment: I was asking why @SamuelElh, not what. So, can you explain (with facts) why `wp_redirect('/dashboard/'); wp_die(1);` won't work? Also, "won't work" is not what you said in the first comment.  Please, try to explain shortly or we can continue in the chat; I'm really curious in the facts behind that assertion (it seems wrong to me by the way).

Comment: maybe this will clarify. `wp_redirect` sets location headers. if you `wp_die(1);` you are outputting content which would typically mean the redirect header is ignored in favour of the output content. if you `wp_die(false);` that might work for the redirect alone, but since you are wanting  to output something, use the jquery/javascript method.

Comment: Now I understand what you mean; I thought you was talking about in a general context, sorry. Anyway, even if you use `exit`, you can not redirect the user sever-side within an Ajax request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, you can not redirect the user from the sever in a Ajax callback. The redirect in the Ajax callback redirecta the Ajax request itself, it doesn't redirect the user to a new location.

I hope you understand what I mean. Remember that Ajax, by definition, is asynchronous.

So, you need to think in another workflow.

For example (just an example, the workflow could be whatever best fit to your needs), the server could respond to the Ajax request with the new location URL; then the Ajax handler (which is client-side) checks the response and performs the redirection:

Ajax calback (server-side):

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'cyb_action_callback' );
function cyb_action_callback() {
    // Something better than esc_url_raw() in this context??
    $data = array(
                      'location' => esc_url_raw( 'https://some.other/location' );
    );
    // See also wp_send_json_error() and wp_send_json().
    wp_send_json_success( $data );
}
```

Ajax handler client-side:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var data = {
        'action': 'my_action',
        'whatever': 1234
    };

    jQuery.get( ajaxurl, data, function( response ) {
            window.location.href( response.data.location );
   }

}
```

Comment: I actually wrote this after posting my question - and it works absolutely fine. Just wondering if there are any disadvantages of using window.location.href to redirect from within jQuery?

Comment: I'm not a jQuery/JS expert but I don't see the disadvantages of `window.location.href()` within jQuery. Others prefer `window.location.replace()`.